# How do I use TShellTreeView

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

This is with Delphi XE7. I have a procedure which adds nodes to a TtreeView. The TreeView is created at run-time and added to a Panel. Then this code is run to build the Tree.

```
var
  node0, node1, node2, node3, node4, node5: TtreeNode;
begin
  Tree.Items.Clear;
  node0 := Tree.Items.Add(nil, 'Client Folders');
  node1 := Tree.Items.AddChild(node0, 'C:\files');
  node3 := Tree.Items.AddChild(node1, 'Folder 1');
  node2 := Tree.Items.AddChild(node0, '\\Westdc2\dev');
  node4 := Tree.Items.AddChild(node2, 'Folder 2');
  node5 := Tree.Items.AddChildFirst(node4, 'Folder 3');
```

That works correctly; I get client folders with two folders below it: C:\files and \westdc2\dev and folders 1-3 below those.

[image: With TtreeView]

But if I change the definition of Tree to TShellTreeView (and in the .Create), it doesn't work. I just get Client Folders added and nothing else.

[image]

This is the same with or without the Tree.Items.Clear which removes the system folders when TShellTreeview is used.

Comment: Isn't the entire point of the shell tree component that it is populated automatically with the contents of your file system?

Comment: Certainly it does that but all the methods to extend it (as I'm effectively doing) are there. It's poorly documented which is why my title is How do I use TShellTreeView.

Comment: But the TShellTreeView is a fairly tight wrapper around Windows' shell objects represented by interfaces which are generated by Windows.  Are you actually interested in shell objects, or what?  I think your q needs to be clearer about why you want to use TShellTreeView and what your objectives are.

Comment: If I told you how I thought it was to be used, is there any guarantee that you'd find that information useful? Surely you are trying to solve a specific problem. If you want help with that then you should described the problem.